# Running functions from excel add-ins in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, add-in

I want to use a function from an add-in in excel and apply it to some data i have simulated in python. Is there any modules that can achieve this?

So far I have some code that generates a bunch of data in a dataframe

> ```
>   C1  C2  C3  nC4 iC4 nC5 iC5 neoC5   N2
> 0 90.34364577 5.501069076 3.904211384 0.007948769 0.057467208 0.000466526 0.034502231 0.008775129 0.141913909
> 1 79.87947438 12.95362252 3.845030371 1.445818316 0.526220788 0.072494231 0.010549205 0.007833261 1.25895692
> 2 86.60782828 11.13247803 0.359881389 0.457152395 0.042235431 0.073007703 0.047842406 0.008097507 1.271476856
> 3 90.74757241 3.788506107 3.569925633 1.392985625 0.072023898 0.022338002 0.012729554 0.008827255 0.385091513
> 4 88.60924681 10.01256459 0.037255942 0.339110209 0.523951737 0.026687176 0.099947814 0.005757065 0.345478655
> 5 87.41030916 6.392736471 3.845213545 1.374943254 0.425436195 0.010030404 0.055277379 0.006825753 0.479227839
> ```

I have an add-in in excel that calculates certain properties of gas mixtures in the form of....

=add-in_name(data_range1, data_range2, "GGCV")

is it possible to call this function from python and do all my analysis in python rather than exporting data to a csv.

I have found code that activates macros but I don't know if this applies to add-ins?

```
import os
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists("C://Users/Joey/Desktop/test.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C://Users/Joey/Desktop/test.xlsm", ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run("test.xlsm!gasvle.gasvle")
    #xl.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: Have you _tried_ calling it using the `Application.Run()` method?

Comment: Unfortunately, this only runs a macro. I need to be able to call the add-in and apply my data indexes there...something along these lines: =add-in_name(data_range1, data_range2, "GGCV")